# How many ways can you deal a hand of 13 playing cards that contains four spades, seven diamonds, and two hearts?

Tags: probability

How many ways can you deal a hand of 13 playing cards that contains four spades, seven diamonds, and two hearts? leave the factory form is fine thanks!!!

Comment: A sufficiently talented card dealer can deal the cards in many more ways than one.

Answer (score 2):

There are

$$\binom{13}{7}=1\ 716$$

ways for the diamonds

$$\binom{13}{4}=715$$

ways for the spades

and

$$\binom{13}{2}=78$$

ways for the hearts

In total, we have

$$\binom{13}{7}\times\binom{13}{4}\times\binom{13}{2}=95\ 701\ 320$$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination starting from $13$ since you have $13$ cards and then go backwards by one twice while multiplying since you picked three cards: $13\cdot12\cdot11=1,716$ ways.  Now use $13!$ (13 times 12 times 11 times 10 times 9 times 8 times 7 times 6 times 5 times 4 times 3 times 2 times 1) and divide it by the previous result.  After doing the math, you'll get $3,628,800$.  This works for any and all probability questions similar to yours.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  We must select four of the thirteen spades, seven of the thirteen diamonds, and two of the thirteen hearts.